# How to toggle input methods with just ctrl-shift?

Tags: key-bindings, linux, input-method

I would like to toggle input method in emacs with OS key binding, i.e. `ctrl-shift`, so it behaves like a normal desktop application. In other words I want to rebind `C-\` to just `C-S` without any extra keys.

My keypoints are:

1. I am on Linux
2. I want all key bindings to work regardless of current language, including `evil`-ones.
3. Switching languages should be done on key release (`C-S-%` should not switch language)

I tried to write XKB-interceptor on C, which is listens [XkbActionMessages](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/libX11/specs/XKB/xkblib.html#actions_for_generating_messages)
and sends it back to emacs. It works, but due to [XKB Bug 865](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865) it switches
languages on key press, not release. So it messes with `C-S-x` key bindings.
There is a patch to workaround this bug, but it not covers `XkbActionMessages`
message. Extending that patch is too much for me.

Maybe there is easier way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: The question is not too clear, for me. Do you mean only Control + Shift or those in combination with some other key(s)? Those are only modifier keys.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do.  Note that, if you bind `C-S` at the OS level such that the OS intercepts the keys before they ever reach Emacs, there's nothing Emacs can do about it.

Comment: I want to make `C-S` to switch input methods without any other keys. I know I can't do it within emacs itself, it's more like a linux question.

Comment: @IgorAvdeev you want to switch the system input-method with C-S- or the emacs input-method?

Comment: @PythonNut I want to switch emacs input-method with `C-S` (`toggle-input-method`)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can't be done within Emacs. You'd either have to modify the Emacs source code (the C part, not just the Lisp part) or use a third-party program that intercepts the keyboard action and sends something else to Emacs. We can't help you with that third-party program since it has nothing to do with Emacs.

Comment: Regarding that third-party program, if you're coding something, you can ask for help on [so]. If you're looking for something ready-made, you can ask on [unix.se]; be sure to mention what window manager or desktop environment you're using as many WM/DE perform their own keyboard interception. Also, what GUI toolkit is Emacs using (if you don't understand the question, what binary are you using, e.g. “the `emacs24-lucid” package from Debian”)?

Comment: @Gilles Ok, I will ask on stackoverflow. Thank you!

Comment: I rebind the hotkey to `Shift+SPC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with this [solution](https://github.com/lislon/emacs-switch-lang) on python, which parses xinput and sends a key to emacs window.

Comment: If this solution meets your needs, please accept your own answer so we can mark the question as closed.